# Sawtooth Wave Generator Using Op Amps

Tags: operational-amplifier, wave, function-generator

So I'm trying to design a sawtooth wave generator that goes from 2.5V to 3.25V. I'm using this design:
[image: Sawtooth Design]

I'm getting a voltage range from around -4V to 4V. Is there any way for me to get 2.5 to 3.25 by editing the values in this circuit? If not is there any other configuration that will help me achieve this, preferably using op amps and/or mosfets.

Edit:
Thank you for the quick responses I was able to work something out.

Comment: You can use another op-amp to offset and scale the signal. There's a worksheet here: http://www.ti.com/lit/an/sloa097/sloa097.pdf and an online calculator here: http://www.daycounter.com/Calculators/Op-Amp/NonInverting-Op-Amp-Resistor-Calculator.phtml that might be of use.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Well, at least this much works good, so it is best to leave it alone and do the level shifting downstream. Use a DC blocking capacitor, a resistors and diode to get rid of negative voltage. Now you have only 0 to 4 volts to fix. Add a 2.5 volt offset, then subtract 2.75 volts to get 2.25 to 3.25 volts.

Answer (score 1):

Your desired hysteresis is 0.75V but your observed is 8V (implying a +/-10V swing at the output of the comparator U1A) so decrease R2 by a factor of 0.75/8 to 3.75K.

You want it centered at +2.875V so add a resistor from the non-inverting input of U1A to the negative supply. Value should be 12/2.875 * 3.75K or 15.65K

That gets you the desired swing and the duty cycle is unaffected, but the frequency will be different (about 10x higher) because the hysteresis is less, so increase the capacitor by the inverse ratio to R2 or 8/0.75 to give you 2.1uF or leave the cap the same and increase both R3 and R4 by that ratio.

And better to replace the 1N4xxx with 1N4148 or similar switching diodes.

Answer (score 0):

To convert a -4 volt to +4 volt signal to +2.25 >> +3.25 range it is best done downstream of your oscillator. Try this circuit. I omitted the bypass capacitors for a clear view, but do not forget them.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmw3xu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>